# Stylesheet empty in JSP

Tags: java, css, jsp

When this page loads, I am able to see the actual stylesheet files under sources in the correct directory; however, they are empty. When I navigate to another page, the stylesheets load correctly and are present. I would like to know why this is happening.

page.JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1' />
    <jsp:include page="../../style.jsp"></jsp:include>
</head>
<body>

<div class='main'>
    <h1>blah</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.JSP

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/two.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/one.css' />
```

Folder Structure

```
webapp

      style.jsp 
      css
        one.css
        two.css
      jsp
        xhtml
           page.jsp
```

Comment: what is the url you are using for page.jsp ? http://myserver/jsp/xhtml/page.jsp ? Because css is relative to url.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/a/v/123456789123123123 -- it's a generated token for the user.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is http://127.0.0.1:8080/a/v/123456789123123123, 
The relative path to the CSS is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='../../css/two.css'/>
```

You may also use an absolute path /css/two.css :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/css/two.css'/>
```

Comment: I am getting the same result, empty stylesheets in the sources, however, the css directory is outside of the a/v directory whereas before it was in it @PascalHeraud

Comment: The path is correct, nothing is appearing inside though

Comment: Maybe you could provide us a working example for comparison